# Angular 2.4.9 : @Types issues

Tags: angular, npm, typescript-typings, package.json, typing

I've got an issue when i run "npm start" :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJ2DU.png

It seems to be some @types error...
My package.json :

```
{
  "name": "g-dex",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Application for Ebex - Bureau d'expertise",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "copy": "./html_cpy.sh"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.4.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.9",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.9",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.9",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.9",
    "@angular/router": "3.4.9",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "moment": "^2.15.1",
    "primeng": "^1.1.4",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.9",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.2",
    "systemjs": "0.19.41",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^6.0.54",
    "concurrently": "^3.1.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "2.0.10"
  }
}
```

What is wrong in my package.json ? Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

PrimeNG 4.0.RC1 is released yesterday you can try with that. It is now using angular 4.0